# How to save and load user input on WPF textboxes, richtextboxes and checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a simple simple WPF application for Windows, the idea is to have a tabletop rpg's character sheet on a pc instead than on paper, so the layout is just plenty Textboxes and checkboxes for storing the stats and two richtext panels for notes and inventory.

I'm struggling to find an efficient way to save all the data when closing the app (or at the press of a button) and then loading it when it's opened again, all the solutions I've found so far seem overly complicated for a little project like this. 
At this point i'm stuck with loading every field with the respective setting I've created, but it doesn't seem really efficient given the number of fields and I think this could will also give me problems with the rich-text boxes. Nonetheless I also have no clue on how to save the setting before closing the app.

Is there a way to just dump all the fields content in a file (xml maybe?) and load them or any kind of a more straightforward solution? I'm afraid I'm missing something and I'm on the wrong path overcomplicating an issue that could be handled very easily, so any advice is really appreciated.

I'm trying to get this thing done quickly, it's just something i'm making for my group that will be used by 4 people at most so I'm not really worried about best practices

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `Dataset`, arranging all the needed data in it (like 1 `column` for every `textbox` you got on your rpg-sheet) You then store the given data in 1 single `row` of the `Dataset` and write it to an `xml-file`, which can be loaded when you start your application the next time: Code-Snippets:

Creating a dataset:

```
_dataSet = new DataSet();
          //possible dataset-settings can be implemented here
        _dataSet.Tables.Add(table) //adding a created table
        for (int i = 0; i < koordinaten.Count; i++) //filling the dataset's table with your data
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["charclass"] = textBoxCharClass.Text;
            row["HP"] = textBoxCharHP.Text;
            //etc.
            table.Rows.Add(row);}
```

Saving your dataset as xml-file:

```
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "XML-File|*.xml";
        sfd.Title = "Save Char-Information";
        sfd.ShowDialog();

        if (sfd.FileName != "")
        {
            System.IO.FileStream fs = (System.IO.FileStream) sfd.OpenFile();

            switch (sfd.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1: dataset.WriteXml(fs, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);                   
            }

            fs.Close();
        }
```

Opening the xml-file:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "XML-File|*.xml";
        ofd.Title = "Open Char-Information";
        ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (ofd.FileName != "")
        {
            System.IO.FileStream fs = (System.IO.FileStream) ofd.OpenFile();

            switch (ofd.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1: dataset.ReadXml(fs.Name, XmlReadMode.Auto);
            }
            fs.Close();
```

Here's the [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN-documentation, in case you need further information :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is the simplest of apps I'd definitely have a data "model" that represents a character you can save, load etc (build in xaml serialization being simple and easy), and bind that to the UI. Ideally, you'd have a View, which deals with the display, a ViewModel which has all the properties and methods supporting the view and a Model that represents the data iteself. It might be overkill for you (unless you're already familiar with it), but if not, it's the MVVM pattern and is industry standard for WPF. Simply having an object to bind to is a "shortcut" version.

```
public class Character : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int age = 20;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set
        {
            if (age != value)
            {
                age = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }
    }

    private string name = "Default Name";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Spells> spells = new ObservableCollection<Spells>();
    public ObservableCollection<Spells> Spells
    {
        get { return spells; }
        set
        {
            if (spells != value)
            {
                spells = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Spells");
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Would it take a while? Yes. Would it mean you have a much more usable, and expandable? Yes. If you are doing this exercise simply because you like typing more than scribbling on note-paper, okay - maybe just having on-screen text boxes and nothing behind it is acceptable.

If you are doing it to have something to eventually add features to other than displaying things on screen (say, 'searching' or filtering spells or abilities, applying specific effects like "fatigued" that adjust stats appropriately etc) or especially if you are trying to learn more about programming/software dev then definitely put the extra effort in.

If you really are only interested in making a skin that you can write in and just want this one feature of saving/loading there's a way I think might work.

If you name all your UI compoennts "NameTextBox" etc etc you can use reflection to loop through them and store and retrieve information depending on the type.

For example:

```
    <StackPanel Margin="20">
        <TextBox x:Name="AgeTextBox"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Notes"/>
        <Button Content="Save" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I can search for all textboxes and do what I want with their contents, in a generic way. This just outputs to the console, but you could save to a text file, csv or xml:

```
        var fields = typeof(MainWindow).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (FieldInfo FI in fields)
        {
            if (FI.FieldType == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                TextBox value = FI.GetValue(this) as TextBox;
                Console.WriteLine(FI.Name + ":" + value.Text);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Produces:

```
AgeTextBox:23
NameTextBox:Bob Bobson
Notes:Is a very nice Character
```

And similar could be done in reverse.

Comment: Nice suggestion of using OOP what it's for: using objects... :) To improve your answer, I would suggest using a ViewModel, rather than binding directly to a model object. You can then pass a model to the ViewModel's (and set properties of the VM to that); and then update the properties of that model as and when necessary. That way you can set a method to save the character's details when "Save" is clicked, otherwise you're just updating the properties directly with the textboxes (i.e. if the window is closed and not saved, the properties will remain as what they'd been changed to)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure whether to go full MVVM in the answer. Might be a bit daunting to someone who's feeling like simply having an object might be too much. I'll edit and add it in as an option, but not explain in too much detail.

Comment: I agree with it potentially being a little daunting. But as they say "start as you mean to go on..." *(whoever they are)*. There's no harm in suggesting what you think is the *right* way to solve a problem (and potentially future/deeper problems at the same time). I once read someone's philosophy on answering SO questions, which was something like "Think about my answer before you downvote: am I just trying to answer the OP, or am I trying to solve a deeper problem that will prevent future issues/questions" (I'm para-phrasing, obviously) :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data being stored isn't of a sensitive nature, have you thought of using a JSON / XML file to save your output?

Using a JSON file you could store variable values (IE: checkbox state) as well as text for any required text boxes (if required this can also be serialized which would help protect against unwanted tampering externally, if that became a problem).

Then read the data back in from the file on application startup.

I'd recommend you look @ [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

and more specifically for serializing to file,

[Serialize Json to file](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializewithjsonserializertofile.htm)